# JQUERY to auto-populate a select input from another select input

Tags: php, javascript, forms, jquery

EDIT 1

I am getting courseID from this code:

```
    $coursesOutput = '<option value=""></option>';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
        $courseID = $row['courseID'];
        $courseName = $row['name'];

        $coursesOutput .= '<option value="' . $courseID . '">' . $courseName . '</option>'; 
    }
```

My php script is as follows (returning an echo statement)

```
    <?php

    include ("includes/connect.php");

    $courseID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['courseID']);
    $sql = "SELECT tee1, tee2, tee3, tee4, tee5 FROM courses WHERE courseID='$courseID' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $tee1 = $row['tee1'];
  $tee2 = $row['tee2'];
  $tee3 = $row['tee3'];
  $tee4 = $row['tee4'];
  $tee5 = $row['tee5'];
    }

    $teesOutput = '<option value="' . $tee1 . '">' . $tee1 . '</option>';

    if($tee2 != ""){
  $teesOutput .= '<option value="' . $tee2 . '">' . $tee2 . '</option>';
    }
    if($tee3 != ""){
   $teesOutput .= '<option value="' . $tee3 . '">' . $tee3 . '</option>';
    }
    if($tee4 != ""){
  $teesOutput .= '<option value="' . $tee4 . '">' . $tee4 . '</option>';
    }
    if($tee5 != ""){
  $teesOutput .= '<option value="' . $tee5 . '">' . $tee5 . '</option>';
    }

    echo '' . $teesOutput . '';
    die();
    ?>
```

I am not getting any ajax errors but still nothing populating in my tee selector.
Hope this helps, once again I am overwhelmed by the support here, unbelieveable!

End EDIT 1

I have been unable to figure this AJAX-JQUERY feature out for awhile now. It should be an easy spot for good jQuery programmers.

I want to be able to auto-populate my tee select input after a user selects their course. This is a golf app and courses have several different tee color schemes so each will be course specific.

So far my broken codes are:

HTML

```
<form id="formAddScore" action="addscore.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <p class="profile_label">Select Date:</p>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="score_input" />

    <p class="profile_label">Select Course:</p>
    <select id="course" name="course" class="score_input" onchange="populateTee(this.value)">
        ' . $coursesOutput . '
    </select>

    <p class="profile_label">Select Tee:</p>
    <select id="tee" name="tee" class="score_input">

    </select>

    <p class="profile_label">Actual Score:</p>
    <input id="score" name="score" class="score_input" type="text" size="10" />

    <p class="profile_label">Score ESC (Equitable Stroke Control):</p>
    <input id="scoreESC" name="scoreESC" class="score_input" type="text" size="10" />
    <br/>

    <input id="btnAddScore" name="btnAddScore" class="btn_score" type="submit" value="Add Score" />

</form>
```

JQUERY

```
function populateTee(courseID)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'includes/populate_tee.php?courseID=' + courseID,
        success: function(data) {
        $("#tee").html(data);
               }
    });
}
```

PHP

populate_tee.php script WORKS, so I won't waste your time including it.

I am fairly certain the problem is in the above JQUERY-AJAX script.

Any help would be wonderful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output that is returned by `populate_tee.php`?

Comment: Are you getting any `.ajax` errors? Those could be seen in the browsers console.

Comment: You also need to mention where courseID comes from. Try copying the actual output in the `course` select from the page source.

Comment: have you triple-checked that 
- populateTee() is getting the correct courseID when it is supposed to?
- populate_tee.php is outputting the correct HTML?
- the headers the browser is receiving in the reply are correct?
- the data in success function is correct?
- the behaviour is consistent between different browsers?

Comment: Are you passing the data in json format - I mean in which format the data is?

Comment: Okay, now its much clearer. Just one question, did you check if you PHP callback is forming the correct options list by the data from the DB? Also, I made a correction above, always put a `die()` after an AJAX callback echoes the final output!

Comment: @rutwick added the die thanks for that tidbit, how would I check my php scripts callback?

Comment: I mean, whatever PHP code is called by your AJAX, should stop execution after it has written the final output back. Hence the die. Did the code work? You marked it as accepted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does courseID come from? Try logging it into the console.
Does this help?

```
function populateTee(courseID){
   $.ajax({
           url: 'includes/populate_tee.php?courseID=' + courseID,
           success: function(data) {
                    //Assuming you're returning the tees list as an indexed array
                    var ops = '';
                    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        ops += '<option>'+data[i]+'</option>';
                    }
                    $("#tee").html(ops);
           }
   });
 }
```

Comment: $("#myselect").html("<option value='text'>text</option>");

Comment: There could be multiple options.

Comment: hi guys, much appreciative of the quick responses, i'm blown away at all the help. This is my first post and am wondering how to reply to this thread other than just a comment?

Comment: Not yet Rutwick, would like to post more code to show where I am getting courseID from and what I am returning from my php script, how would I do this?

Comment: @BillChambers - You should edit your original post and start your edit with **Edit 1** or **Update 1**

Comment: @rutwick, I posted edit 1 above hopefully it helps, I might be in a little over my head here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onChange event on select i suggest use of jquery .change() method. Try following code it should solve the problem.

```
 $('#course').on('change', function () {
          var courseID = $(this).val();

          $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'includes/populate_tee.php?courseID=' + courseID,
                success: function(data) {
                $("#tee").html(data);
               }
              });


      });
```

Comment: `each` is not required here as it would mean sending an AJAX request for every option in the select. Editing your answer.

Comment: I guess you are right but since you are not using select multiple it should not cause any trouble. Although you can alter the code with in the change method.

Comment: Hi, More simpler approach in this case will be to use $(this).val(); I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I feel dumb, I can't figure out how to reply to my own thread, please help!