# JQUERY-AJAX auto populate a select box

Tags: php, javascript, forms, jquery

I have been drilling away at this AJAX auto population feature for awhile now with no success. I have a bit more comlicated of implementation, so I searched the web for a tutorial in which to step through and I can't even get it working. I think if I can get some help getting this simple example (below) to work and I can scale it up and implement as needed. Code below:

HTML

```
    <body>
    <p>Select Dropdown</p>
    <p>
        <select id="selection">
            <option value="">- Select Item Here -</option>
            <option value="food">List of Food</option>
            <option value="animals">List of Animals</option>
            <option value="flowers">List of Flowers</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>DropDown Result</p>
    <p>
        <select id="selectionresult"></select>
    </p>
    <p id="result">&nbsp;</p>
    </body>
```

JQUERY

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#selectionresult").hide();
        $("#selection").change( function() {
             $("#selectionresult").hide();
             $("#result").html('Retrieving …');
             $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
               data: "data=" + $(this).val(),
               url: "demo/jquery-autopopulate-select-dropdown-box-response.php",
               success: function(msg){
                       if (msg != ""){
                         $("#selectionresult").html(msg).show();
                   $("#result").html("");
                 }
                 else{
                   $("#result").html('<em>No item result</em>');
                 }
               }
            });
         });
      });
      </script>
```

FINALLY, PHP

```
<?php

$expectedValues = array(“food”, “animals”, “flowers”);

$selectionArr['food'] = array(‘pizza’, ‘spaghetti’, ‘rice’);
$selectionArr['animals'] = array(‘cat’, ‘dog’, ‘girrafe’, ‘pig’, ‘chicken’);
$selectionArr['flowers'] = array(‘rose’, ‘sampaguita’);

if (isset($_POST['data']) and in_array($_POST['data'], $expectedValues)){
    $selectedArr = $selectionArr[$_POST['data']];

    foreach($selectedArr as $optionValue){
        echo '<option>' . $optionValue . '</option>';
    }
}

?>
```

Everything seems to work just fine with this code, but still no options show up in the selectionresult selector?

Any ideas, gents, and thanks in advance.

I know I can get this with your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+select+add

Comment: What's the difference between this question and the one you asked earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133204/jquery-to-auto-populate-a-select-input-from-another-select-input

Comment: Please do not mind my answering of my own question. I forgot to correct some syntax in the php script after copying it from the source. FOR EXAMPLE:

POSTED:
    $expectedValues = array(“food”, “animals”, “flowers”);

 EDITED:
    $expectedValues = array("food", "animals", "flowers");

 and so on. But hey, this code works for someone trying to implement something like this.

Hope this helps someone.

My apologies Stack Members.

Comment: @Mike B got this thing figured out now, just need to scale it up, sorry to waste your time.